# Comparing two large binary files in C

Tags: performance, c, file

I'm trying to read two sufficiently large binary files, comparing them and printing the offset at which they differ. I'm using `fread` to read the binary files and `memcmp` to compare them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

clock_t start, end;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double cpu_time_taken;
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    printf("\nArgument count:  %d", argc);
    printf("\nFile 1 is: %s", argv[1]);
    printf("\nFile 2 is: %s\n", argv[2]);
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("\nInsufficient Arguments: \n");
        printf("\nHelp:./executable <filename1> <filename2>\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fp1 = fopen(argv[1],  "rb");
        if (fp1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError in opening file %s", argv[1]);
            return 0;
        }

        fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "rb");

        if (fp2 == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError in opening file %s", argv[2]);
            return 0;
        }

        if ((fp1 != NULL) && (fp2 != NULL))
        {
            start = clock();
            compare_two_binary_files(fp1, fp2);
            end = clock();
            cpu_time_taken = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("\nTime taken to compare: %f", cpu_time_taken*1000);
        }
    }
}


int compare_two_binary_files(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
    char tmp1[16], tmp2[16];

    size_t bytes = 0, readsz = sizeof tmp1;
    int count = 0;
    while (!feof(fp1) || !feof(fp2)){
        fread (tmp1, sizeof *tmp1, readsz, fp1);
        fread (tmp2, sizeof *tmp2, readsz, fp2);
        count += 16;
        if(memcmp(tmp1, tmp2, readsz)){
            for(int i=0; i < readsz; i++){
                printf ("%d: 0x%02x ",i, tmp1[i]);
            }
            printf("\n%x", count);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you mmap them: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html ?

Comment: Have you considered using a shell script to wrap the standard `cmp` command?  If not, at least look at its source and use that as a basis for your version.

Comment: Better `printf ("%d: 0x%02x ", count+i, tmp1[i]);` to have global offset of differences. With `i` you see bytes in current block. Also, use `sizeof tmp1` instead of `sizeof *tmp1` and `count += sizeof tmp1`.

Comment: @N74 It is certainly worth considering `mmap`, but there are situations where `mmap` won't work. Not all operating systems support `mmap`, and on OS where it is supported it isn't all file systems which support it. Moreover `mmap` only works on regular files. And if you want to support files larger than your address space, the `mmap` solution isn't going to be much simpler.

Comment: @N74 The most important reason is that there is no `mmap` in C.

Comment: A lot of answers mentions your small buffer size and suggests random options, but note that the C standard already defines a mandatory constant in stdio.h named `BUFSIZ` which is designed to be a good size for a file buffer, and must be _at least_ 256 (it is the same size as fopen() uses default). I suggest using that, since someone already decided a "good" value for your particular platform. On my debian machine it's 8192.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm trying to read two sufficiently large binary files, comparing them and printing the offset at which they differ.

`compare_two_binary_files()` is faulty for various reasons.

1. The offset in which they differ can readily exceed the `int` range.  Recommend the widest integer available instead.  File sizes are not limited by the integer types available, yet `uintmax_t` is a very reasonable assumption of being sufficient for a file size.
2. Checking `feof()` only ignores the possibility of a rare input error messing up the compare.
3. `compare_two_binary_files()` can return without a returning a value.  A compiler warning should have occurred.  Enable all warnings or use a better compiler.
4. Ignoring the return value of `fread()` is wrong.
5. `if(memcmp(tmp1, tmp2, readsz)){` is questionable.  The `if()` is true when the buffer differ.

Suggested alternative:

```
// Use something more generous than 16.  Maybe even 4096 or 64k and allocate buffers
#define CMP_N 256

// Return value:
// 0: files compare equal in content and length, fp1 size saved as offset
// 1: files differ, fp1 longer, fp2 size saved as offset
// 2: files differ, fp2 longer, fp1 size saved as offset
// 3: files differ at offset
// -1: fp1 trouble reading.  Unspecified data in offset
// -2: fp2 trouble reading.  Unspecified data in offset
int compare_two_binary_files_alternate(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2, uintmax_t *offset) {
  char tmp1[CMP_N], tmp2[CMP_N];
  size_t n1, n2;

  rewind(fp1);  // start at beginning and clear error
  rewind(fp2);
  *offset = 0;
  do {
    n1 = fread(tmp1, sizeof *tmp1, sizeof tmp1 / sizeof *tmp1, fp1);
    if (n1 == 0 && ferror(fp1)) {
      return -1;
    }
    n2 = fread(tmp2, sizeof *tmp2, sizeof tmp2 / sizeof *tmp2, fp2);
    if (n2 == 0 && ferror(fp2)) {
      return -2;
    }
    size_t n_min = n1 < n2 ? n1 : n2;
    if (memcmp(tmp1, tmp2, n_min)) {        // Quickly find if file contents differ ...
      for (size_t i = 0; i < n_min; i++) {  // Slowly find where they differ
        if (tmp1[i] != tmp2[i]) {
          *offset += i;
          return 3;
        }
      }
    }
    *offset += n_min;
    if (n1 > n_min) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (n2 > n_min) {
      return 2;
    }
  } while (n1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `off_t` standard?  It's intended for holding file offsets.

Comment: @PeterCordes `off_t` is not part of the C standard.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9073667/2410359  Perhaps you are thinking of  `fpos_t` as used in `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()`?

Comment: And if you want to be a bit more efficient than "slowly" you could do a binary search for the difference. E.g. first check the first `COMP_N / 2` bytes, if they differ check the first `COMP_N / 4`, etc. This will locate the difference in logarithmic rather than linear time which is useful especially with more generous block sizes like 4096 (on average requiring 6 steps instead of 2048) although I'm not sure what the effect of caching would do in the "slow" loop version.

Comment: @CompuChip Your suggestion is still O(N) - yet perhaps with a linear improvement.  N/2 1st iteration + N/4 2nd iteration + N/8 3rd + N/16 4th ... --> N.  Given that files are large, efficiency of comparing the last block is likely minor.  More significant speed improvements could be had with larger buffers, memory mapped I/O buffer, etc.

Answer (score 12):

> ```
> fread (tmp1, sizeof *tmp1, readsz, fp1);
> fread (tmp2, sizeof *tmp2, readsz, fp2);
> count += 16;
> if(memcmp(tmp1, tmp2, readsz)){
>     …
> }
> ```

You are discarding the return values of the `fread()` calls, blindly assuming that they both successfully read 16 bytes.

It is unclear what the return value of `compare_two_binary_files(…, …)` means.  In fact, you sometimes don't return a value at all.  Your compiler should have warned you about that problem.

File I/O should be done a block at a time: 512 bytes, 1024 bytes, or 2048 bytes would be a more reasonable chunk size than 16.

Technically, most of the time is spent waiting for I/O.  `cpu_time_taken` is a misnomer: what you're measuring is called "wall clock time".

Comment: compare_two_binary_files(…, …) should just print the offset where the difference is found. It should not return any value, but my compiler didn't allow return so I just included an int return type.
And could you elaborate on why cpu_time_taken is a misnomer and is there any right way I can measure the time taken to compare the binary files?

Comment: If you have nothing to return, change the return type to `void`.

Comment: 4096 would be a good default size.  1 whole page on some common architectures like x86, and also 1 disk physical sector on modern rotational media, and many NAND flash devices.  The kernel buffers I/O in normal hosted C implementations that run under a modern OS, but I wouldn't count on C stdio buffering input to do `read()` system calls in page-size chunks.  (It might though.  Or better, if stdio uses `stat(2)` to ask the OS for the optimal I/O block size.)

Comment: If the files are "sufficiently large" - I was thinking Gbytes at a minimum, if not Tbytes - then the OP should look at the asynchronous I/O library.

Answer (score 10):

- `if ((fp1 != NULL) && (fp2 != NULL))` test is redundant. If one of them happened to be `NULL`, the program is already terminated.
- Don't print error messages to the `stdout`. There is `stderr` for that purpose.
- When printing to stdout, keep in mind that it is usually line buffered. The text stays in the internal buffer until a newline is printed. That's why it is important to print a newline *after* the message, not before.
- `printf("\nError in opening file %s", argv[1]);` doesn't tell the most important part: *why* did `fopen` fail. Print `strerror(errno)` as well. Combining the above bullets,

  ```
      fprintf(stderr, "Error in opening file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
  ```

  You'd need to `#include <errno.h>` for that.

Comment: "why it is important to print a newline after the message" is not necessarily sufficient.  [What are the rules of automatic flushing stdout buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359).  Consider `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: I like the idea of of informative error messages, yet printing a faulty file name is sometimes itself a problem.  At a minimum, it is useful to include sententials to demarcate the iffy file name.  `file %s` --> `file \"%s\"`.

Comment: @chux: that's part of why error messages should be printed on stderr, which is unbuffered by default.  If `stdout` isn't going to a terminal, full buffering is normally fine.  Unless you're writing a shell or something that prompts and waits for input, that someone might want to automate with pipes, you don't need `fflush` after printing a newline.

Comment: @PeterCordes Agree about "is _normally_ fine".  Using `fflush(stdout);` always flushes regardless of implementation aspects of the character, line fully buffered mode or OS/shell properties.  And it also does not oblige a change in  functionality (adding a final `'\n'`).

Comment: @chux: My point was that for *this* case, it's clearly better to end the message with a newline and print it to stderr.  Either of which would be sufficient for this case, unless abnormal termination that doesn't flush stdout is possible.  (e.g. `abort()`.)  But both, as suggested by this answer, are better for formatting reasons as well as flushing correctness.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers focus nicely on the comparison function, so I'll just mention a couple things about the start of main.

What does this do when you run the program with no arguments?

```
printf("\nFile 1 is: %s", argv[1]);
printf("\nFile 2 is: %s\n", argv[2]);
```

You can't check `argv[1]` or `argv[2]` if there are not enough arguments.  However, you do check that immediately after, so you can just cut-paste them a few lines down.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double cpu_time_taken;
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    printf("\nArgument count:  %d", argc);

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("\nInsufficient Arguments: \n");
        printf("\nHelp:./executable <filename1> <filename2>\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nFile 1 is: %s", argv[1]);
        printf("\nFile 2 is: %s\n", argv[2]);
        fp1 = fopen(argv[1],  "rb");
        //...
    }
}
```

You can simplify it further still - your `else` is unnecessary because the `if` terminates the program, so it won't run the content of the `else` regardless. I find it easier to read when there are fewer indentations, but maybe that's just me. Also, the `if` catches an error in running the program, and informs the user. If this is being called from a script, you'd want to return something other than 0, because 0 indicates success. So you can make one more simplification:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double cpu_time_taken;
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    printf("\nArgument count:  %d", argc);

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("\nInsufficient Arguments: \n");
        printf("\nHelp:./executable <filename1> <filename2>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nFile 1 is: %s", argv[1]);
    printf("\nFile 2 is: %s\n", argv[2]);
    fp1 = fopen(argv[1],  "rb");
    //...

}
```

I echo the advice in other answers about putting the newline at the end of your print, rather than before.